# Intel 1155 Chipset Temperature Specifications

Tags: temperature

I have an MSI Z68A-G45 (G3) motherboard (socket 1155) with an i5-2500 processor.  I'm trying to keep an eye on temperatures/fan speeds/etc., and I can find the specifications for the CPU, but not the chipset.  What's the recommended and maximum temperatures for this chipset?

Answer (score 0):

[Intel's ARK page](http://ark.intel.com/) generally has all details.

Since the Z68 page doesn't have the details, here's what Ambalur received in an email

> The TCase for the set is 104°C and the Tjmax is 108°C.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sathya!  Unfortunately I'm pretty sure it's the Z68 Express chipset I need information for, and the specs for that one don't seem to include a TCase value.  I've e-mailed Intel asking for the information.

Comment: @Ambular oops, my bad. If you get a reply from them, do post an answer here!

Comment: I did get a response.  According to what they sent me, the TCase for the set is 104°C and the Tjmax is 108°C.  If what I've turned up elsewhere is accurate, this should mean I'm looking to keep it under about 74-78°C, does that sound right?

Comment: @Ambular that about sounds right